# Way to calculate vibration

Tags: python, frequency, librosa, vibration, dft

I am reading a paper about synthesis. One of the parts is talking about calculating vibrato, and I want to follow their way to do the same thing. However, I am new to signal processing and am not sure whether the method I found is correct or not.

This is the part of the paper [MIDIDDSP-paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.09312.pdf)
[image]

First, f0 means fundamental frequency, which I already calculated.

But then I am not sure the way to calculate the f0(t).

I've found a method called [librosa.stft](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.stft.html), computing discrete Fourier transforms (DFT) over short overlapping windows. The code is something like

```
y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('trumpet'))
S = np.abs(librosa.stft(y))
```

Yet, I don't know what's the next step and whether the method is right.

Hope someone could tell me the way to calculate vibrato, I appreciate it!!!!

Comment: Can you link to the paper in question?

Comment: How do you compute f0? The FFT/DTFT has to be applied on the f0 estimate, not on the original audio

Comment: Okay, I added the paper link. 
Actually, the code of computing f0 was provided by my professor. But it seems that he didn't put FFT method inside the  f0 function, so i've done the fft function after calculating f0

Comment: @JonNordby Hi, could you help me, thanks